# LateInitializationError: Field '_imagePicked@20490806' has not been initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Getting this when trying to initialize data.

```
 [The following LateError was thrown building UserImagePicker(dirty, state:
_UserImagePickerState#adbb9):
LateInitializationError: Field '_imagePicked@20490806' has not been initialized.]
```

Here's the code:

```
  late File _imagePicked;

  final _picker = ImagePicker();

  void _pickImage(ImageSource src) async {
    final pickedImageFile = await _picker.getImage(source: src);

    if (pickedImageFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imagePicked = File(pickedImageFile.path);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: try "late File? _imagePicked;"

Answer (score 1):

Nullable non-`late` fields in Dart are initialized to `null`:

```
String? string;
print(string);  // prints null
```

The same is not true of `late` fields. A `late String` cannot contain `null`, because `null` is not a valid value for the type `String` (which is the whole point of null safety).

Instead, `late` fields are *uninitialized* until they are first assigned. If you try to get the value of an uninitialized field, you get a `LateInitializationError`, rather than it returning null.

In your case, I suspect there is a line somewhere that contains:

```
if (_imagePicked == null) {
  // set _imagePicked
}
```

The easy fix is to simply make `_imagePicked` nullable. This gives 2 benefits:

1. You don't have to store an extra boolean called `_isImagePicked` that tracks whether you have set this value
2. The compiler will force you away from unsafe behaviour (like trying to call `_imagePicked.foo()` when `_imagePicked` is null)

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the question where you call the _pickImage() function? I think when you call the function _pickImage(), there's nothing in the File _imagePicked. When you build the app, _imagePicked has nothing and this will cause the app to crash.